# AngularJS: Using custom filter in ng-model workaround

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm fairly new to AngularJS... I've built a custom filter that takes the current seconds since midnight and compares it to the value of the `open` / `closed` time of the data object. It works great, and tells me if the store in the model is open or not.

However, now I want to be able to allow the user to sort the data based on whether the store is open or closed. I have used several input checkboxes to filter other sorts of data, for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="query.has_parking" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="" > Has Parking
```

Which allows the user to filter stores that have parking.

The data coming in has the hours structured like this:

```
{
    sunday_open: 720,
    sunday_close: 1020,
    monday_open: 600,
    monday_close: 1320,
    tuesday_open: 600,
    tuesday_close: 1320,
    wednesday_open: 600,
    wednesday_close: 1320,
    thursday_open: 600,
    thursday_close: 1320,
    friday_open: 600,
    friday_close: 1320,
    saturday_open: 600,
    saturday_close: 1320
}
```

So my filter finds the current day, then compares it with the values supplied and returns Open or Closed.

```
.filter('is_open', function() {
    return function(data) {
        var currentDay = new Date().getDay();
        var currentMSM = (new Date().getHours() * 60)  + (new Date().getMinutes());
        var open, close;

        switch(currentDay)
        {
            case 0:
                open = data.sunday_open;
                close = data.sunday_close;
                break;
            case 1:
                open = data.monday_open;
                close = data.monday_close;
                break;
            case 2:
                open = data.tuesday_open;
                close = data.tuesday_close;
                break;
            case 3:
                open = data.wednesday_open;
                close = data.wednesday_close;
                break;
            case 4:
                open = data.thursday_open;
                close = data.thursday_close;
                break;                                                              
            case 5:
                open = data.friday_open;
                close = data.friday_close;
                break;
            case 6:
                open = data.saturday_open;
                close = data.saturday_close;
                break;                              
        }
        // so now I have the open and close time of today at the specified store
        // compare it to the current seconds since midnight on the client
        return (currentMSM > open && currentMSM < close) ? "Open" : "Closed";
    };
})
```

But now I want to use the same value for a checkbox input to allow a user to sort the open and closed stores, and to be honest, I'm not even sure where to start.

I know I cannot use filters in `ng-model`, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you are almost there - you already have the logic to identify if the store is closed or open. All that you need to do is apply this as a filter to the display of stores - which brings me to my question - how are you displaying the stores? Using `ng-repeat` or something else? Could you post some code on how you are displaying the stores? Which model are you using to display the stores and what are the properties / attributes of this model?

Comment: Also, could you create a plunkr with the bare minimum code related to this question?